# parse date with moment from GMT format

Tags: date, momentjs

I am not able to parse the date in the following format 'February 4, 2020, 3:15:14 PM GMT-6'

I tried to specify format but no luck.

With no format specified I get the warning:
Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format.
How do I get a parsed date from this string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Moment doesn't have a parsing token for offsets like `GMT-6`.  The offset must be at least two digits to work correctly with the `Z` token.  You can use a regex replace to alter your string before parsing.

```js
var input = 'February 4, 2020, 3:15:14 PM GMT-6';
var adjusted = input.replace(/(GMT\+|-)([1-9])/, '$10$2');
var m = moment.parseZone(adjusted, 'MMMM D, YYYY, h:mm:ss A [GMT]Z');

m.format() //=> "2020-02-04T15:15:14-06:00"
```

(There are probably improvements to the regex that could be made, but this one works.)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I thought I can't find a way to make moment parse it.